# How to use webauthn without key fob

Tags: authentication, firefox, web, webauthn

I have tried my firefox 62 and chromium on various webauthn examples and I could not make any of them work. Are those supposed to work without special hardware? I activated `security.webauth.webauthn_enable_softtoken` in `about:config`. Though I can't find much documentation on what exactly it does. Is webauthn ever supposed to work without special hardware?

- https://webauthn.bin.coffee/
- https://webauthn.io/
- https://webauthndemo.appspot.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be able to use the "softtoken" in Firefox you have to enable it and disable the usbtoken:

```
security.webauth.webauthn_enable_softtoken=true
security.webauth.webauthn_enable_usbtoken=false
```

Then you can test on https://webauthn.bin.coffee/ and https://webauthn.io/ .

However, I have no idea how exactly it works and where its documentation is located.

---

As for the question how to use Webauthn, it should be possible according to the standard, but if browsers support it is another thing. Check this comment: https://github.com/w3c/webauthn/issues/1027#issuecomment-411441722

> The spec is indeed written with hardware-backed authenticators (external or built-in) as the main concern, but WebAuthn does not in any way forbid integration of purely software-based authenticators.

...

> It's perfectly possible for browsers or browser plugins to provide support for software authenticators, although WebAuthn provides no standardised API for doing that.

Comment: Note that webauthn.io only works with the "Require User Verification" checkbox disabled (hidden in "Advanced settings" of the site).

Comment: Even toggling the settings as this answer suggests, I'm not able to register on webauthn.io. (The "Require User Verification" checkbox mentioned in the comment above no longer exists; there is a similar "User Verification" dropdown, and I tried every value, to no avail.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, WebAuthn is evolving technology. Supported only in Firefox/Chrome Desktop and Chrome Mobile browsers.

You'll need some U2F stuff like https://www.yubico.com/products/yubikey-for-mobile/
or AddOns like https://krypt.co/

Comment: The [w3c recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#use-cases) explicitly mentions "roaming authenticators" (= U2F USB/NFC key) and "platform authenticators" (fingerprint readers, TPMs, ...).
Both firefox and chrome currently only seem to support roaming authenticators. 
I would expect that many users would be happy to use platform authenticators based on Window Hello, Gnome Keyring or similar, i.e. without the need for an hardware key.
Is anybody aware of such an authenticator?

Answer (score -1):

Webauthn is pretty widely supported now, and it works in modern browsers without a roaming authenticator (a USB device or similar). It's very easy to test on the site you mentioned, https://webauthn.io/

https://caniuse.com/#search=webauthn